# Multiline comments on field in protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

How to write multiline comments for message fields in `.proto` fields?
Official doc is not says about it.
For example I have message:

```proto
message LocationResponse {
  City city = 1; // city info, will be filled only when `with_city` option is requested
  Country country = 2; // country info, will be filled only when `with_country` option is requested
  repeated Subdivision subdivisions = 3; // subdivisions info, will be filled only when `with_subdivisions` option is requested
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
message LocationResponse {
  // city info, will be filled only when `with_city` 
  // option is requested
  City city = 1; 
  // country info, will be filled only when `with_country` 
  // option is requested
  Country country = 2; 
  // subdivisions info, will be filled only when `with_subdivisions` 
  // option is requested
  repeated Subdivision subdivisions = 3; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's clearly mentioned in the document:

`To add comments to your .proto files, use C/C++-style // and /* ... */ syntax.`

Please see the example below:

```
message Response {
    // This is a single-line comment
    uint32 status = 1;
    /*
      This is a multi-line comment, 
      The second line in this comment.
    */
    string message = 2;
}
```

Please see the document link:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#adding-comments